# Generating a UUID by limiting the characters' length

Tags: node.js, uuid, node-uuid

I am using the node js library `uuid-int` to generate unique id.

```
const id = 0;
const generator = UUID(id);
const uuid = generator.uuid(); // e.g. 3425779734788360
```

However I want to reduce the length of the number while making sure it is still unique.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use another library e.g. https://shortunique.id

Comment: Thank you ! this did the trick . Can't ask for a better solution !